# Generating a random spatial distribution of ClockGauges

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to generate a spatial distribution of clock gauges using the Graphic ClockGauge[]?

I had in mind something like the standard documentation example below except with ClockGauges:

```
Graphics[Table[{Circle[RandomReal[4, {2}], .5]}, {8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to control the placement? Like with `Inset`?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly more fun to use [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) to place [`ClockGauge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html) randomly on the world map.

First generate a random list of [`TimeZone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeZone.html) locations

```
randZones := EntityList["TimeZone"][[#]] & /@ 
    (Flatten@{RandomInteger[{0, 100}], RandomInteger[{101, 200}], RandomInteger[{201, 300}], RandomInteger[{301, 470}]})
```

Then place them on a world map with [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

```
GeoGraphics[{
  Table[
    Inset[ClockGauge[Quiet@DateObject[DateList[TimeZone -> randZones[[i]]]]], 
      First@GeoLocation[randZones[[i]]], Center, 50],
    {i, 4}]
  },
  GeoRange -> "World",
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  GeoGridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.4, 0.5]
]
```

[image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 1):

As kuba mentioned, you could simply use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

```
Graphics[Inset[ClockGauge[], #, Center, 4] & /@ RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}]]
```

[image]